# c# gridview row click

Tags: c#, gridview, click

When I click on a row in my GridView, I want to go to a other page with the ID I get from the database.

In my RowCreated event I have the following line:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add(
     "onClick",
     ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(
          this.grdSearchResults, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex));
```

To prevent error messages i have this code:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // .NET will refuse to accept "unknown" postbacks for security reasons. 
    // Because of this we have to register all possible callbacks
    // This must be done in Render, hence the override
    for (int i = 0; i < grdSearchResults.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(
                new System.Web.UI.PostBackOptions(
                    grdSearchResults, "Select$" + i.ToString()));
    }
    // Do the standard rendering stuff
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

How can I give a row a unique ID (from the DB) and when I click the row, another page is opened (like clicking on a href) and that page can read the ID.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have the solution.

This is what i have done:

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "location.href='view.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "id") + "'";
}
```

I have putted the preceding code in the RowDataBound event.

Comment: Id cast e.Row.DataItem, Eval is slow and doesn't allow refactoring to pick up the fact that you might have changed the ID field's name

Answer (score 20):

Martijn,

Here's another example with some nifty row highlighting and a href style cursor:

```
protected void gvSearch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#ceedfc'");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=''");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='patron_detail.aspx?id=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "'");
  }
}
```

The code above works in .NET 3.5.  However, you can't set your id column to Visible="false" because you'll get a blank query string value for your id key:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSearch" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvSearch_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" Visible="false" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="First" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="Last" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="state_name" HeaderText="State" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So change the first column to this instead:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="id" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide" />
```

Add this css to the top of your page:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .hide{
      display:none;
    }
  </style>
<head>
```

But to hide the first cell of your header row, add this to your gvSearch_RowDataBound() in code-behind:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
  e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "hide";
}
```

Obviously, you could have hidden the id column in code-behind too, but this will result in more text in your markup than a css class:

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;");
e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
```

Comment: This look complete solution:) which includes HTML/Code behind code!

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void gvSearch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string abc = ((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "location.href='Default.aspx?id=" + abc + "'";    
    }
}
```

Comment: Navigation through JS is bad, if it's not an internal site. Google won't index this.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void gvSearch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    { 
        string abc = ((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); 
        e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "location.href='Default.aspx?id=" + abc + "'";     
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void gvSearch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
{     
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridViewRow gvr = e.Row;
            string abc = ((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();         
            gvr.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:location.href='Default.aspx?id=" + abc + "'");
        }         

   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can your ID be related to the data item displayed in the gridview?

If so you can use e.Row.DataItem, and cast it to whatever type it is.

Answer (score 0):

row click in grid view redirect to other page

```
    protected void gvSearch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
             string abc = ((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
             e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "location.href='Default.aspx?id=" + abc + "'";
        }
    }
```

works absolutely fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RowCommand event of the grid view for it. In your button/link where you wnat to set the click on, set the CommandName and CommandArgument, which you can accees at the EventArgs paramter of the event method.

Answer (score 0):

JohnB, Your code works very fine, i added just a little hack to avoid alternatingRowStyle ruining after mouseout.

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=''");
```

Changed to:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "if(" + e.Row.RowIndex + "% 2 == 0) { this.style.backgroundColor=''; } else { this.style.backgroundColor = '#E8F7EA'; }");
```

If there's a better way to do it, please let me know, but it's working perfect for me.

Greetings.