# How to tick a Checkbox in ASP.NET GridView without going to Edit mode

Tags: c#, gridview, asp.net-3.5

I have a Checkbox template column in a ASP.NET 3.5 GridView. Now the user has to click 'Edit', tick the Checkbox, then click the 'Update' or 'Cancel' button, which raises an event that we use to update database.

Is it possible to just check the box without going into Edit mode at all and raise a Checked event so that we can update database ? Alternately we can iterate through all rows, identify ticked rows and update them to DB in a loop.

Any pointers helpful.

Thanks,
Chak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

Row click event of gridview...

Ref this [c# gridview row click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331231/c-gridview-row-click)