# asp.net GridView CheckBox not clickable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am gathering data and everything works, the check box is checked if the bit in the database is `1` and unchecked if it is `null` or `0`.

However the check box seems disabled, I need the user to be able to check the box, which will update the database as well.

Here is my check box:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="submitted" HeaderText="Submitted" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</Columns>
```

Am I missing something to make this check box clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place you're GridView in edit mode in order to check or uncheck the CheckBox.  There are a few ways you can do this.  This simplest is probably to add this property to your GridView markup:

```
AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
```

And then click the edit button that gets created in the row you want to modify.

You can place a specific row into edit mode via code-behind by setting the `EditIndex` of your GridView to the desired row index*:

```
yourGridViewID.EditIndex = 1;
yourGridViewID.Databind();
```

**I used "1" as an example above, but you can use any row index that's within the bounds of the GridView.Rows collection*

Comment: Thanks for the help, I went a completely different method and used a button as all the frame work was already there to make adding a button quicker.

Answer (score 1):

I think this link / quote from docs below might explain your problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxfield.aspx

> A check box is disabled (read-only) until the data-bound control
>   displays a record that contains the check box in edit mode. For more
>   information on how to put a record into edit mode, see the
>   documentation for the parent control that contains the CheckBoxField
>   object.

See this post for the best way to handle this...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1951150/1246574

**EDIT**

You're also missing `runat="server"` in your CheckBoxField code snippet that you posted.

Comment: You actually don't need `runat="server"` on these, since it is a sub-element of a server-side databound control (it's part of the `GridView.Columns` collection).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I went a completely different method and used a button as all the frame work was already there to make adding a button quicker.