# How can I redirect from a grid view when a row is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagrid, response.redirect

In my grid View I have a template field button when clicked it redirects the page and sends the msgid along with the url, Is it possible to do that by clicking anywhere in the row, i.e if i  click on the msgid or title field then it should redirect to respond metric page with the row msgid. Just like a select button,

```
MsgID      Title       Actions

1          First        Image(Which redirects)
2          second       Image(Which redirects)
```

in this table if the user clicks on any spot in row 1 then the page should redirect, it has to perform the same action of Image. How can I do that

```
  <asp:GridView ID="Grid_Messagetable" runat="server" BorderWidth="5" GridLines="None"
                    CssClass="gridTable" SelectedIndex="0"
                     DataKeyNames="MsgID" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                    OnRowDataBound="MyGrid_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true"
                    OnSorting="gridView_Sorting" >                                     <Columns>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="MsgID" HeaderText="MsgID" SortExpression="MsgID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" ItemStyle-Width="35%" HeaderText="Subject" SortExpression="Title" />                                                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_ViewDashBoard"  ImageUrl="Styles/Images/icon_dashboard.png"
                                    Enabled="True" Width="" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("MsgID", "ResponseMetric.aspx?MsgID={0}") %>'
                                    Text='Send' ToolTip="View DashBoard"></asp:ImageButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331231/c-sharp-gridview-row-click

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RowDataBound` event to attach a click event to the row.

Markup:

```
redirect = function(){
    window.location.hef = "home.aspx";
}

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ...>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "redirect();"
}
```

Comment: Where should I enter the Markupcode if I want to redirect to home.aspx page