# select row from a gridview that during the execution has a new datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

On the first column is the id and want to select it to be redirected to a page that has more details that row.

He goes good if datasource is not changed but if it is modified or receive ID of the initial data, or gives me error for that initially did not have many rows.

My code is:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    string strCell = row.Cells[1].Text;
    string myPageUrl = "Meci.aspx?ID=" + strCell;
    Response.Redirect(myPageUrl);
}
```

Please tell me how can I change it to work well!

Comment: It is a bit difficult to understand what are the issues you are facing. Please, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist and add the clarifying information. Because for now it not clear what is the DataSource of that `GridView`, how it is used and what does that error "that initially did not have many rows" mean.

Comment: Also, I'd like to point that databinding an entire gridview just to do a redirect according to a data from a single row is quite an inefficient and error-prone solution. You may be interested in something similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068782/how-can-i-redirect-from-a-grid-view-when-a-row-is-clicked.

Comment: I have a calendar on, when I select another day on the calendar  my gridview show other matches. If I use this code on initial day work but if I change the data from calendar the gridview change too and when I whant to select some I receive information from the first grid view or: Index was out of range.

Comment: That is the information that you should have added to your question from the start - no one here knows absolutely anything about your project, except what you have written in the question. So any piece of information is relevant. Though sometimes there can be too much information. That's why it is a good idea to read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist once again, and create a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok, now I realized that I did not put the question correctly, but I'm in a hurry I have project to be done to college and do not have much time. Now that you understand the problem can you recommend a solution? Please!

Comment: The problem is that even now I don't understand you problem [no pun intended] - it is probably caused by some inconsistency between databindings and postbacks, but what exactly is going on and how exactly it **should be** is still unclear. As I have already told you, without  [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would be nigh impossible to help you.