# Redirect via datagridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working in ASP.Net / C#. I am trying to make the server redirect to another page using via the rows in a datagrid, however, my code doesn't seem 
to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  protected void GridView1_RowCreated()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        Color color = row.BackColor;
        string color2 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color);
        Session["" + row.Cells[0].Text + ""] = row.Cells[0].Text;
        //row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "zz(); return false;");
        /*if (row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate)
        {
            row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "redirectFunction(); return false;");
            //row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='   #FFFFFF';");
            //row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='" + color2 + "';");
            //row.Attributes.Add("onclick", cookie.Value = row. GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text);
            //row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "zz(); return false;");
        }
        else
        {
            //row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='   #FFFFFF';");
            //row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='" + color2 + "';");
            //row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "zz(); return false;");
        }*/
    }
}

        public void redirectFunction()
        {
    Response.RedirectPermanent("View.aspx");
        }

        Other page 
        if(Session["session"].ToString() != null)
        {
            // do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are adding a client side on click event and then trying to call a c# method which won't work.

This code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "redirectFunction()");
    // Or if you want to pas in an id
    row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "redirectFunction(" + rowId + ")");
}
```

is adding a javascript click event to the row and you are telling it to call a javascript method. You then need to add the javascript method to your aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirectFunction() {
       alert("do you see this??");
       window.location = "View.aspx";
    }
</script>
```

I have added an alert statement, you can get rid of it but do you see this popup? If not check for any javascript errors on the page.

You could also do this with jQuery (it's much easier):

```
$('.yourrowclassname).click(function () {
    window.location = "View.aspx";
});
```

This means you do don't need to add the attribute in code, just use/add a class to the row.

Comment: just calling the javascript function from the selectedIndexChanged of the gridview does nothing.

Comment: I have updated the code above. If you are still stuck, can you provide more information.

Comment: Also the SelectedIndexChanged will fire when the row is selected, not clicked on. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onselectedindexchanged.aspx

Comment: It works, however; for some reason the function is only call for every other row in the datagrid that I click on.

Comment: Do you mean on alternating rows? If so, make sure you haven't put your row.attribute... code in your if (row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate) statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this feature by using the SelectedIndexChanged event for the GridView. From there, you can grab all the properties and information of your object that you will need to display in your View.aspx page.

Comment: I've tried, but the simple code wouldn't work.
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1)
{
 row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "redirectFunction(); return false;");
}

        public void redirectFunction()
        {
   Session["session"] = Gridvidew1.SelectedIndex.Cell[0].Text;
            Response.RedirectPermanent("View.aspx");

Answer (score 0):

Check this post here, this will help you achieve what you are trying to do
https://stackoverflow.com/a/331662/125551

just add session["var"]= val or send that value in url and get that value in page_load on other page from querystring instead of session