# Event OnClick of a Row in a GridView

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, gridview

I want to open a pop-Up with the `openPopUp` javascript command when the user click on a row in my GridView.

How can I do that ?

I saw some tips on [c# gridview row click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331231/c-sharp-gridview-row-click) but how can I open a popUp on the row click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openPopUp` is not a JavaScript api. You might have seen it is some plugin or somewhere else. May be you are looking for `window.open()`.

If you want to see how we can listen to row click event in a gridView you can try this.

```
$('#gridViewId tr').click(function(){
    //code here
    window.open(...);
});
```