# how to redirect to another page by clicking on a gridview row

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

i m using a grid view in my page and my requirement is that when i click on a row (anywhere on a row), it should be redirected to another page which will display the details of the row selected.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+redirect+to+another+page+by+clicking+on+a+gridview+row'

Comment: use the html anchor tag https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331231/c-sharp-gridview-row-click)

Comment: use 'validateRow', or 'rowdoubleclick' events,

Answer (score 1):

if you have jQuery loaded.. then:

```
$('rowID-or-className').click(function(){
    window.location.href = 'https://docs.google.com';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnSelectedIndexChanged`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDummy" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

---

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do some business and redirect
}
```

a full example can be found [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Row-Click-event-to-GridView-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working Example:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#id').click(function(){
   window.location.href = 'www.test.com';
  });
  });
 </script>
```

```
 <div id="id">CLick</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On gridview RowDataBound event you can do this easily. this is a one way to do it and you can pass any data from code behind also and from that specific row also by using this method:

here is a code simple example: it will set the onclick event for all rows in your gridview.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "window.location.href='YourPage.aspx'";
    }
}
```

if you want to pass some value from that clicked row, for example you have a label inside that row which is having a unique ID of row data then you can pass this id to your page and get all data on that page load event, you can do like:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string idd = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblId")).Text;
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "window.location.href='Youpage.aspx?id="+idd+"'";        }
}
```

Hopefully it will resolve your problem.